# Pairing error with Jawbone Mini Jambox

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I just bought a Mini Jambox (Jawbone) wireless bluetooth speaker. It work like a charm with my Nexus 7, iPhone 4 and MacBook Pro. Unfortunatly I can not make it work with my Ubuntu 14.04 Laptop.

What I have done:

1. Enable Bluetooth on my Laptop
2. Run the bluetooth-wizard command
3. Select the Mini JamBox device

After one minute, the wizard display an error message:

> Failed to connect to the device...

I also have the following log:

```
(bluetooth-wizard:18445): Bluetooth-WARNING **: CreateDevice failed: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed: Page Timeout

** (bluetooth-wizard:18445): WARNING **: Setting up 'MINIJAMBOX by Jawbone' failed: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed: Page Timeout
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 14.04, and I found that these steps were necessary with a fully updated system:

- Add `Disable = Media` in the [general] section to /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf (`sudo vim /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`)
- And make sure bluez-tools is installed (`sudo apt-get install bluez-tools`)
- Also make sure to restart the bluetooth service, just in case (`sudo service bluetooth restart`)
- Then connect your Jawbone device, it should now pair successfully.
- Now, the change to audio.conf we made earlier seems to prevent the device to show up in the list of audio devices. What you need to do it to remove the line we added (Disable = Media), then restart the bluetooth service, and your device should now show up in the list of audio devices! Make sure it's turned on in the Bluetooth manager, it might be off after restarting the service.
- One last note, you have to change the audio setting from HSP/HFP to A2DP, otherwise the sound might be crappy ...

Your mileage may vary, good luck!

Comment: Amazing! These steps didn't work for me on Xubuntu 15.04 but they did on Ubuntu 15.04. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Download the Synaptic Package Manager and look for additional bluetooth libraries to download.

It worked with my minijambox.